# Adding ArcGIS webappviewer to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I just started working with QGIS. I just found a webappviewer that I would like to put in a work of mine for my exam.

The map can be found on: https://provincieantwerpen.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=64dd9849dbd64807960b9d7090fe2255

Answer (score 2):

You can't add an ArcGIS Web App to QGIS. However, you can add the data used in that Web App to QGIS.  It's not a WMS, it's an ArcGIS Rest FeatureService. The Feature Service URL is:

https://services6.arcgis.com/QBuWyjJyJZDKpVHF/arcgis/rest/services/TW_Herentals/FeatureServer

To add it, open the QGIS Browser panel, scroll down to ArcGIS REST Servers, right click - New Connection... and add the URL above and give it a name then click Ok. You can then open the new connection and drop the layer onto the QGIS map canvas.

[image]

The way to figure out the FeatureService URL, is to open the developer tools (ctrl-shift-i) in Chrome, go to the network tab, zoom around and look for a URL with "FeatureServer" or "MapServer" in it and copy that URL discarding everything after the "FeatureServer" or "MapServer" part.